# Rudin's PMA: Problem 9.17. How can I compute $f'$ and $g'$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling with part c) of problem 17 of chapter 9:

Let $f=(f_1, f_2)$ the mapping of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$f_1(x,y)=e^x \cos y$,  $f_2(x,y)= e^x \sin y$

*c) Put $a=(0,\pi /3)$, $b=f(a)$, let $g$ be the continuous inverse of $f$ defined in a neighborhood of $b$ such that $g(b)=a$. Find an explicit formula for $g$, compute $f'(a)$ and $g'(b)$ and verify formula (52).*

Let $g(x,y)=(\ln \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \arctan(y/x))$, then $g(f(a)) = g(1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)=(0,\pi/3)=a$.

How could I directly compute $g'(b)$ or $f'(a)$. Is it possible to consider them as the directional derivatives of $g$ and $f$ since they are both differentiable?

Comment: $f$ looks a lot like the fan favorite $e^{x+iy}$

Comment: $f'(a)$ and $g'(b)$ are the actual derivative (Jacobian) matrices, are they not?